# Does disabling HBase table allows all running scans complete

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

Before dropping a table in HBase we have to disable it. What will happen when "disable" command is issued for a table on which some scans are already running.

1. Does the scan fail?
2. Or the running scans are allowed to finish gracefully and then table is disabled?